# Removing duplicate letters from string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

After reading some questions here about how to remove char from the string. I tried to implement it and make a function.

The function takes a `sorted chars` string and its job is to delete the repeated letter from the text/string, means any string will be in alphabetical order

```
void removeDuplicate(string& text)
{
    int n = ;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == text[i - 1])
            text.erase(i - 1, 1);
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. **UPDATE**: The function work great but if there are more than 2 repeated letters ("aaa" >> "aa"), it just delete one letter.. **So, may someone help and point to the error?**
2. Isn't there another built-in function that can delete all duplicate letters?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Is this for educational purposes? Otherwise use `std::unique`.

Comment: too lazy for a full answer but just some hints, you save the length of the text before the loop, now what do you suppose happens when you erase characters inside the loop?

Comment: @juanchopanza yes it's for educational purpose

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl That means that the strings length is constant.
I will give a try thanks

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl 
It works like charm. Thanks. I wish to thank you in person. I spent many hours on it.

Comment: @amrelghobary actually that should only fix your first problem with the out of range error, but won't work if you try some string with 3+ of the same letter like "aaa", I think I'll write an answer anyways.

Comment: You have to decrease a length each time you erase from string:

    void removeDuplicate( std::string& text)
    {
        int n = text.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == text[i+1])
                text.erase(i , 1);
                n--;
                
        }
    }

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Yes, when more than 2 repeated letter, it just delete one letter. why?

Comment: @amrelghobary look at @private's comment. When you erase the 2nd character the character that was formerly on 3rd position is now on 2nd position, so you'd have to check the 2nd position again in the next iteration, but you increment `i` for the next iteration. That basically means, if you erase a character **don't increment `i`** if you don't erase, **do increment `i`**

Comment: and decrement n each time you do erase

Comment: @amrelghobary anyways, that isn't something to write yourself other than for experimentation with looping, the duplicate question linked to got the idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl yes it worked. can't you make an answer to take the reputation?? I updated the question that supposed to remove the duplication

Comment: @amrelghobary nah, just leave it as duplicate. Also I'm on my netbook and hate to write longer answers with code on it's keyboard... That's why I try to give hints in comments when I happen to check new questions.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl I didn't get it "that isn't something to write yourself". I just made it for education and learn how to manipulate things.

Comment: @amrelghobary for learning looping/manipulating in a loop it's fine, it just shouldn't be used in real programs, since it's trivial to forget that the index of the next item shifts if you erase an item, and there are nice functions to do it already. (std::unique and string::erase in the linked answer).

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl You don't like reputation :). Thanks a lot. you amused me. nice blog by the way.